# Generate quoted symbol in Emacs Lisp macro

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am creating a simple macro to disable show trailing whitespace in certain major modes (I will loop this macro in a dolist loop later):

```
(defmacro non-trailing-whitespaces-modes (mode)
  (let ((hook (intern (concat  mode "-mode-hook"))))
    `(add-hook ,hook (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))))
```

After this macroexpand: `(macroexpand '(non-trailing-whitespaces-modes "eshell"))`, the result is

```
(add-hook eshell-mode-hook
          (lambda nil
            (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

I want `eshell-mode-hook` to be `'eshell-mode-hook`, otherwise it will cause error.

Comment: So add the missing `'` to the macro code.

Comment: Anonymous lambdas in hooks aren't great: it's hard to modify/remove them without a name.
I prefer a dedicated named hook function for each mode.

Comment: It works. I thought adding `'` to `,hook` make it quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the body of the macro to begin `(add-hook ',hook ...)`

Answer (score 1):

No need for a macro, here:

```
(defun non-trailing-whitespaces-modes (mode)
  (let ((hook (intern (concat  mode "-mode-hook"))))
    (add-hook hook (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))))
```